# Limiting to two workspaces in raring?

Tags: 13.04, workspaces

I want to use just 2 workspaces in my Raring install, instead of the default two rows of two workspaces each. Is there a way to do so without using compiz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can install "unity tweak tool" on ubuntu software center,
launch it, and go to workspace setting

[image]

then it will show this

[image]

so you can change the number of workspace horizontally or vertically